# How to remove withstanding space from ImageView after clipping its canvas?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-imageview, clip

I'm having an ImageView displaying a Bitmap. In it's onDraw method I use clipRect to cut off some pixels from the bottom. This works fine, but the height of the ImageView doesn't get adjusted to the modified canvas and so an unwanted space remains. How can I get ridd of that?

I've been trying to reduce the parent's height accordingly and set it's clipChildren to false but it caused some issues.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
{
    Path clipPath = new Path();

    clipPath.addRoundRect(
        new RectF( 0, 0, width, height - (int) ( watermarkHeight * scale ) ),
        cornerRadius,
        cornerRadius,
        Path.Direction.CW );

    clipPath.addRect( 0, 0, width, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW );

    canvas.clipPath( clipPath );

    super.onDraw( canvas );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use "Adjust View Bounds" property of your ImageView